# Linq to Entities Navigation Performance

Tags: linq, entity-framework

in my application I query EF code first with linq to entities.

My db context contains two entities Application and Status

```
class Application
{
    public string Id {get; set;}

    public string DossierId {get; set;}
    public virtual Dossier {get; set;}

    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate {get; set;}

    public string LastStatusId {get; set;}
    public virtual Status LastStatus {get; set;}
}

class Status
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

This is my query

```
var dateDiff = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12);

var retVal = db.Applications
    .Where(app => app.CreatedDate > dateDiff)
    .GroupBy(app => app.DossierId, 
             app => app, 
             (dosId, app) => app.OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault())
    .Select(app => new GridData()
    {
        Id = app.Id,
        ActualState = app.LastStatus.Name,
        ApplicationDate = app.CreatedDate
    })
    .OrderBy(app=>app.ApplicationDate);
```

Then I page the result with a page size of 30.
My performance problem depends on the ActualState navigaton property: if I comment it out the execution is very fast (less than a second) while if I query ActualState the execution is very slow as it enumerated all the records (ten seconds).

Have you got any hints?

Thanks,
Alessandro

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that Proxy is enabled and that I have a custom mapping relation between Status and Application

```
this.HasRequired(app => app.LastStatus)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(app => app.LastStatusId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: It's difficult to give specific recommendations, but it's possible to describe decision way. First, see value `retVal.ToString()` in the debugger. It contains SQL query. Copy this query to SQL Management Studio, and check execution plan. I can assume that there's no index in the `Status` table.

Comment: Of course there is an index. The generated SQL contains a left outer join on the navigation property's table which seems to be the slowing item

Comment: What shows the execution plan? Are using seek or scan for `Status` table? What count of rows in the `Status`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the Status via [eager loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

```
db.Applications.Include(p=>p.LastStatus)
```

Your updated code:

```
var retVal = db.Applications.Include(p=>p.LastStatus)
    .Where(app => app.CreatedDate > dateDiff)
    .GroupBy(app => app.DossierId, 
             app => app, 
             (dosId, app) => app.OrderByDescending(t => t.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault())
    .Select(app => new GridData()
    {
        Id = app.Id,
        ActualState = app.LastStatus.Name,
        ApplicationDate = app.CreatedDate
    })
    .OrderBy(app=>app.ApplicationDate);
```

Comment: @ing.alfano Can you paste the generated SQL for both options? (with/without the include)  We can then see if the related objects are being joined correctly in the initial fetch.